# RESTful actions specified in Users controller AND Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm running Rails 4, just made a barebones application and a User model with Devise. I also ran a migration to add a `name` attribute to the User model. I also generated a Users controller, as I want to be able to have a Users `index` page, where all Users are listed. If I specify `resources :users` in my `routes.rb`, then what do I do about methods like `create` in my Users controller, which are already handled by Devise? (I'm aware that this is a rather open-ended question, but some direction would be much appreciated.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the index action in your user controller.

You can do `resources :users, :only => [:index]` in your routes.rb file.